# Using the result of concurrent Rails & Sidekiq jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, concurrency, sidekiq

Sidekiq will run 25 concurrent jobs in our scenario.  We need to get a single integer as the result of each job and tally all of the results together.  In this case we are querying an external API and returning counts.  We want the total count from all of the API requests.

The `Report` object stores the final total.  Postgresql is our database.

At the end of each job, we increment the report with the additional records found.

`Report.find(report_id).increment(:total, api_response_total)`

Is this a good approach to track the running total?  Will there be Postgresql concurrency issues?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: `increment` shouldn't lead to concurrency issues, at sql level, it updates atomically with `COALESCE(total, 0) + api_response_total`. Race conditions can come only if you addition manually and then save the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`increment` shouldn't lead to concurrency issues, at sql level, it updates atomically with `COALESCE(total, 0) + api_response_total`. Race conditions can come only if you addition manually and then saving the object.

```
report = Report.find(report_id)
report.total += api_response_total
report.save # NOT SAFE
```

**Note**: Even with `increment!` the value at Rails level can be stale, but it will be correct at database level:

```
# suppose initial `total` is 0
report = Report.find(report_id) # Thread 1 at time t0
report2 = Report.find(report_id) # Thread 2 at time t0
report.increment!(:total) # Thread 1 at time t1
report2.increment!(:total) # Thread 2 at time t1
report.total #=> 1 # Thread 1 at time t2
report2.total #=> 1 # Thread 2 at time t2
report.reload.total #=> 2  # Thread 1 at time t3, value was stale in object, but correct in db
```

> Is this a good approach to track the running total? Will there be Postgresql concurrency issues? Is there a better approach?

I will prefer to do this with [Sidekiq Batches](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches). It allows you to run a batch of jobs and assign a callback to the batch, which executes once all jobs are processed. Example:

```
batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
batch.description = "Batch description (this is optional)"
batch.on(:success, MyCallback, :to => user.email)
batch.jobs do
  rows.each { |row| RowWorker.perform_async(row) }
end
puts "Just started Batch #{batch.bid}"
```

> We need to get a single integer as the result of each job and tally all of the results together.

Note that Sidekiq job [doesn't do anything with the returned value](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3532) and the value is GC'ed and ignored. So, in above batch strategy, you will not have data of jobs in the callback. You can tailor-made that solution. For example, have a `LIST` in redis with key as batch id, and push the values of each complete job (in `perform`). In callback, simply use the list and summate it.